# Recover the path to a goal state in A* search algorithm

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms

In the [A* search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm), we use a priority queue with heuristic function to find optimum result with minimum cost. But, how do we get the path after reaching goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every node should have been given a pointer to the node it was reached from. Then you only need to follow and reverse a linked list.

Comment: So, I need to modify the priority queue. Okay, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Nightmare, it's not the priority queue you are modifying; you add to each node a pointer to how you got there.  Similarly techniques are used in, e.g., breadth-first search or depth-first search to reconstruct the paths.  See your favorite algorithms textbook.

Comment: Yes, I already know. I used simple array with sort function. I just modify array structure to record pointer, that's it.